# How to drag-move NSWindow with a NSImageView on its contentView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

I'm creating a mini window like the iTunes mini window:

[image]

It's draggable and have a background image on it.

Then I created a `NSWindow`'s subclass and overrides its `initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:` method, and added an `NSImageView` to it:

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag
{
    contentRect.size = CGSizeMake(287, 287);
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:aStyle backing:bufferingType defer:flag];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5]];

        NSImageView *imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){CGPointZero, contentRect.size}];
        imageView.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"MiniWindow.png"];
        [self.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

But after I add the `NSImageView` to window's contentView, the window become undraggable.

How to make the window become draggable again?

Best regards

Comment: I think you are trying to drag your imageview.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create an subclass of `NSImageView` and override `mouseDownCanMoveWindow` method:

```
- (BOOL)mouseDownCanMoveWindow
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This seems a correct and helpful answer (worked for me - thanks!) - why isn't it marked as such?